# awscli: copy only part of the file from s3 to local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to use s3 cp to copy a file (.csv) from s3 to my local machine. The file is large and I wonder if there is a way to only copy part of it, say the first 10000 rows or 5MB of the file.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a **ranged get**:

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket my-bucket --key foo --range bytes=1-10 output.txt
```

See: [`get-object` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html)

You can specify the number of bytes, but not the number of rows because that requires interpretation of the contents.

Comment: Thanks! the '--range' appears twice in your cmd line. I assumed that it just needs appear once? Going to try it

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer the original question but could be a potential solution to to original problem.

You can use **[Amazon S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html)** to perform SQL queries on your .csv files on S3. It's not a full-on SQL but you can do the basics like selecting wanted fields, and use `LIMIT` for selecting say first 10000 lines.

On top of the SQL query, in the [aws cli command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/select-object-content.html) or the [boto3 sdk](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.select_object_content), you can also specify a scan range say from 0 - 5000000bytes.

What's even more amazing is, if you are using the sdks, you get to use a stream object which only fetches a few records at a time. This greatly reduces the memory usage.

Answer (score -2):

I've been using AWS cli extensively.

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/large_file.tar.gz | gunzip -cd | head -n 10000 > first_10000.csv
```